# Descriptions for n, N, V, T, F

Tags: tex-core, expl3

Where can I find descriptions for n, N, V, T, F.  What are they called ?  Generally found after commands.

Comment: You need to give much more context to your questions.  I happen to know what you're talking about, and others who know the answer will know what you're talking about, but if someone doesn't, this question is incomprehensible.

Comment: I do not know what they are called and cannot do a search just for a single letter as I get a limitless number of matches.  I encountered them from `page 111` in `source2e.pdf`.  Perhaps you could edit the question so others can know what I am talking about.

Comment: You've not only had an answer explaining some of these (https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/697107/defining-functions-in-latex3/697108#697108), but you've posted at least one question explaining some of them (https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/697181/code-description-for-tl-if-emptyvtf). In addition to being told some of the terminology, you've also been told the document, section number and page number where you can find the details. So why are you asking again?

Comment: you were told the section of interface3.pdf where all these are described yesterday on your VTF question. why ask the same thing over and over again?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In an `expl3` function, the individual letters that specify the arguments of a command are called its *argument specifiers*. The complete set of them is called the *signature* of the function.

These are fully described in section 1.1 (p.2,ff) of the [`interface3`](https://texdoc.net/pkg/interface3) documentation for `expl3`.

Comment: I fail to comprehend how the documentation has been made so difficult to follow.  They are used freely in `source2e.pdf` without explanation.  And the explanation is in `interface3.pdf`.  When normally one starts with `soerce2e.pdf`.

Comment: The `interface3.pdf` makes some sense and is instructive.  But `source2e.pdf` is in a big mess.

Comment: `source2e` is literally documented code. It's not intended to be a reference manual.

Comment: It would help a lot if there was a document called `Introduction to programming in Latex`.

Comment: Is there a reference manual for designers ?

Comment: Indeed, but when all the software is written on a volunteer basis, the development team do what they think serves the most people, which is providing the software itself and its associated reference documentation. I and many others have managed to learn a lot from `interface3`.

Comment: Perhaps a group across the world could help them write an introduction.  Spend a weekend or something.  Use their students and collaborators.  Or during their conferences when they do them.

Comment: Try https://www.alanshawn.com/latex3-tutorial/

Comment: I have suggested having a single reference and forget all the `source2e.pdf` and `interface3.pdf`.  What most people do is endure the terrible documentation job.  The team goes berserk when  one dares criticise.  But I do it anyway.

Comment: The analysis in the link provided is spot on.  It is shameful that the old folks continue to insist that their documentation and presentations are good.  Certainly they are not.  Certainly not to people who spend much of their time on system complexity.

Comment: Their attitudes can on my nerves most times as they are quite wrong.

Comment: Their attitudes get on my nerves most times as they are quite wrong.  The curse of university academics.